# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Tags: multithreading, jdbc, sqlexception, database-deadlocks

I have a Java batch that runs on multi-threads (usually 16/32). There's a JDBC query that conditionally inserts/updates in a table.

However, some of the records fail due to following error:

```
[CobolThread 34] ERROR (com.splwg.base.support.sql.PreparedStatementImpl) Error executing update for rawSQL:
update TABLE_A s set s.INT_COL = s.INT_COL + 1 where s.PRIM_ID = ?
with 'string' parameter named 'primId' to : '8741104958' to indices: 1
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

In this query, the PRIM_ID column is the Primary key column and there are no other indexes on this TABLE_A. I have gone through many blogs available around this and all they suggest is to avoid the usage of Bitmap index. In my case, there is no bitmap index neither there is any Foreign key involved.

Note: We were using a MERGE statement prior to conditional Insert/Update but it too used to fail for the same reason.

Please help me understand the cause of this issue.

Comment: What other updates are you running? Are there any updates to tables that would have a foreign key reference to `PRIM_ID`? If this is the only update, are you _sure_ that your multithreading code is not allocating the same ID to more than one thread?

Comment: @MickMnemonic, There is no FK reference to PRIM_ID. One additional point I noted recently was the presence of ITL waits on this table in AWR report. I am working on optimizing the INITRANS and PCTFREE parameters for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about the parallelization code, how are you distributing `PRIM_ID`s between threads?

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks appear when multiple DML commands are trying to access same data simultaneously.

[Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00060_deadlock_detected_while_waiting_for_resource.htm) and [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_deadlock.htm) you can find short explanations about this issue. It is a very common behavior of a wrong written SQL command. I think you should rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks, @HelenA for your response. But as i mentioned, DML commands are not accessing the same data. Prim_id is the unique key which is used in the update query. Thus, multiple threads cannot access the same data simultaneously.

Comment: @ShardulDhanorkar did you find an explanation, i'm running into the same problem. I verified mannualy that thread dont access the same primary keys